# Как создать скомплированный файл с цветным текстом и utf-8 на python?

Tags: python, exe

Я решил сделать текстовую рпг игру на python, для создания цветного текста я использовал библиотеку termcolor и еще я использовал много необычных символов для создания рамок и всяких украшений, я создал exe файл при помощи Pyinstaller но он не выводит цветной текст и некоторые символы

Comment: Не выводит символы - проблема используемого консолью шрифта.
Цветной текст - настройки консоли.

Comment: Если что вместо символов там стоят вопросы, разве дело не в кодировке? Ну это ладно, а решение проблем в итоге какое?)